# flycheck thinks functions defined in a macro are not defined

Tags: flycheck, elisp-macros

i use a `define-request` macro to make it easier to define lots of requests to a REST API. each one returns a defun, the request function.

flycheck is unable to discover the existence of these functions. so whenever i use one in my code it complains that it is not known to be defined. this is the case even if i `require` the file containing the definitions.

it is possible to configure flycheck to catch such definitions, can it expand the resulting code of the macros somehow?

otherwise i have to manually add a `declare-function` call after every `define-request`.

I'm using flycheck 33snapshot, on emacs 29.1 on debian. checkers: emacs-lisp, emacs-lisp-checkdoc, and emacs-lisp-package.